# How to switch cases with ( - ) and ( + ) keys presses?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I am working with AutoHotKey. I know I have tagged C also, I think someone with enough C programming knowledge can also help here.

Code below is working for me.
It will read two keyboard input from user and based on what user pressed it will run code for that case.

```
1::
Input Key, L1

if Key=1
    {
        ;your code
}
if Key=2
    {
        ;your code
}   
2::
Input Key, L1

if Key=1
    {
        ;your code
}
if Key=2
    {
        ;your code
}
```

I would like to know if I can add a loop or something if user presses + or - key it will go do one case at a time,  
 
 
for example if user presses + for first time it will do  
1 1 if user presses + again it will do 
1 2 if user presses - it will do 
1 1 
and so on. 
 
 
I am not sure if this is do able or not. 
 
 
I am new to programming. please help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables. A global variable can be accessed anywhere in the program, unlike a normal variable which exists only inside the function.

Example:

```
#NoEnv
#Persistent
SetBatchLines, -1


global myVar = 0


h::
    myVar := myVar + 1
    execute()
return


g::
    myVar := myVar - 1
    execute()
return


execute()
{
    if(myVar == 1)
    {
        ;do stuff
        tooltip, myVar: %myVar%
    }
    else if (myVar == 2)
    {
        ;do stuff
        tooltip, myVar: %myVar%
    }
    else if (myVar == 3)
    {
        ;do stuff
        tooltip, myVar: %myVar%
    }
    else if (myVar == 4)
    {
        ;do stuff
        tooltip, myVar: %myVar%
    }
    else if (myVar == 5)
    {
        ;do stuff
        tooltip, myVar: %myVar%
    }   
    else
    {
        ; nothing
        tooltip,
    }

return
}
```

I hope this is what you were asking, i wasn't quite sure from the question.

Comment: Hi, This is what I am trying to do. So for my current code. I am asking digit input from user 1 or 2 and other number from 0 to 9. so basically from 10 to 29. so if user enter 28, it will execute for 29 and after 28, if user presses - or + it will send another input if user presses - if will send 27, if user presses + it will send 29. I hope I am making sense

Comment: I think need to define a int or something which will save last input from user, and I need another pieace of code which will read last input from that variable and based on what user presses + or - it will send that input. hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

; Some of this is what's called Pseudo code. (not sure if you're familiar). It gives you needs to be turned into actual code...

; Written for AHK...

CurrentNumber = 1

(plus key)::
CurrentNumber += 1
send %CurrentNumber%
return

(minus key)::
CurrentNumber -= 1
send %CurrentNumber%
return

; Not sure if this is what you were looking for or not.. if you want a loop it will be different.
; either way, good luck to you, i'm out..

Comment: Hi, I am sure how to use your code, so for my current code. I am asking digit input from user 1 or 2 and other number from 0 to 9. so basically from 10 to 29. so if user enter 28, it will execute for 29 and after 28, if user presses - or + it will send another input if user presses - if will send 27, if user presses + it will send 29. I hope I am making sense

Answer (score 0):

```
+::
keywait, +, u
{
    If var =
        var = 11
    Else
        var++
}
Return
-::
keywait, -, u
{
    If var =
        var = 11
    Else
        var--
}
Return
```

"var" should have same name with the variable, which has two or one digit number, in your code.

You may use this too

```
NumpadAdd::
keywait, NumpadAdd, u
{
    If var =
        var = 11
    Else
        var++
}
Return
NumpadSub::
keywait, NumpadSub, u
{
    If var =
        var = 11
    Else
        var--
}
Return
```